# Canvas Drawing gets blurred after calling getImageData() method on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, getimagedata

The original canvas renderings are getting blurred after i call getImageData() and copy its content to another canvas on GOOGLE CHROME. Anyone facing similar problems?

Comment: Adding some code and screenshots to your question might help if you don't get any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `getImageData()` to copy an image, just use `drawImage` to draw source canvas into destination:

```
dstContext.drawImage(srcCanvas, 0, 0);
```

As to cause it's hard to tell as you are not providing any examples/code.